# i installed PMM server percona package on a remote server, how can i access now the grafana dashboard/interface?

Tags: mysql, monitoring, grafana, percona

I installed PMM percona tools on a remote server (that I can reach using ipv6) how/where can I run Grafana instance on a local browser so that it is connected with PMM?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install grafana on the same server where you installed PMM, 
after doing that you can just access the grafana interface using your local brower
( es. http://[ip-address]:3000 )
https://www.fosslinux.com/8328/how-to-install-and-configure-grafana-on-centos-7.htm

Answer (score 0):

Did you install it as a docker container or as a VM appliance? Appliance should have an exposed IP you can point your web browser at. Docker container should have a port mapped through, and you can then point your browser at that port on the host.